# Springboot 3 Webflux + Spring Security CSRF disable not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Today I upgraded my Webflux REST API demo application from springboot `2.7.x` to version `3.0.0`. On testing found for POST Calls with SpringSecurity I am getting `403 Forbidden` with message `An expected CSRF token cannot be found`. I double checked my security config and don't find any problem.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users", "/api/v1/users/**").hasRole(ReactiveConstant.SECURITY_ROLE_ADMIN)     // Only admin can do POST
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/users", "/api/v1/users/**").hasAnyRole(ReactiveConstant.SECURITY_ROLE_USER, ReactiveConstant.SECURITY_ROLE_ADMIN)       // user can only do GET
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().formLogin().disable()
            .build();
    }
```

This is working in SpringBoot 2.7.5 version. My `build.gradle` file,

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
}

group = 'io.c12.bala'
version = '0.2.1'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    // Springboot utils
    implementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-tools'            // For Reactor debugging in IDE
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.1.0'
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.85.Final:osx-aarch_64'     // For macos netty DNS issue.
    implementation 'com.aventrix.jnanoid:jnanoid:2.0.0'

    // Springboot testing with Spock test framework
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    // Spock test framework
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.3-groovy-4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.3-groovy-4.0'

    // Reactor test framework
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
}
```

I am not seeing any changes to CSRF in SpringSecurity documentation.

My POST Call,

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic am9objpIZWxsb1dvcmxkQDEyMw==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "emailId": "John.doe@example.com",
  "userId": "j.doe"
}'
```

Response: `403 Forbidden`

```
An expected CSRF token cannot be found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced the same symptoms when migrating my webflux application to Spring Boot 3.0.0 today, which worked perfectly with 2.7.5. So I googled for "csrf-disabling no longer working" and found this and some few (!) other posts...

However it was an annotation change of Spring security 6, that caused the problem: @EnableWebFluxSecurity contained "@Configuration" in 5.x version (I checked) - but obviously does no longer and has to be added explicitly.

Thus the complete SecurityWebFilterChain bean was not found after migrating... Now the working code looks as follows:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration       // <- this annotation was missing but worked with Spring Security 5.x
public class AccountWebSecurityConfig { 

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                        ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                        ServerAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler,
                                                        ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic(httpBasicSpec -> httpBasicSpec
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    // when moving next line to exceptionHandlingSpecs, get empty body 401 for authentication failures (e.g. Invalid Credentials)
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            )
            .authorizeExchange()
    //...
}
```

As your FilterChain - snippet does not show the annotations at your class, chances are, you may also missing the @Configuration..

In my case now everything works as before :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This fixed my application too. I was missing `@Configuration` in my security config class too.

Comment: One additional detail that may help when the WebClient unit tests are failing: be sure you ```@Import(YourCustomHttpSecurityConfiguration.class)``` at the top of your unit test to ensure that your custom security configuration is pulled in.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you!